# Vim replace all characters up to first comma

Tags: string, vim, replace

I am trying to use VIM to replace all the characters up to the first comma in a large text file (10mb+)

I have something that looks like:

```
foo,bar,sun
apple,pear,goose
monkey,pig,baby
```

and I want it to look like:

```
bar,sun
pear,goose
pig,baby
```

Comment: You say "replace" but you really are deleting characters.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following should do it

```
:%s/^[^,]*,//
```

Explanation:

- : Command mode
- % Apply to every line
- s Substitute
- / match

  - ^ From the start of the line
  - [^,] Any character other than comma
  - * (See previous) Repeated or empty
  - , A comma
- / replace

  - nothing
- / finished

Alternatively you can use sed:

```
sed 's/^[^,]*,//' -i FILENAME
```

or

```
sed 's/^[^,]*,//' FILENAME > NEWFILENAME
```

Edit: minor formatting and explain ":"

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
:%norm df,
```

to run the normal command `df,` on every line in the file. Which deletes from the beginning of the line up to and including the first comma.

Read `:help :normal`

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
[esc]:%s:^[^,]*,::
```

**edit**: of course you can also use cut:

```
cut -d , -f 2- < mybigfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

`:%s/.\{-},//`

This version uses a non-greedy quantifier `\{-}` which causes the preceding dot to be matched 0 or more times but as few as possible (hence it is non-greedy).

This is similar to using a `*?` in most other regular expression flavors.